Merging two nonadjacent disks
I want to merge at least part of Disk 0 with Disk 1 to increase the space on my C drive. I have found numerous posts about merging nonadjacent partitions on the same disk, but there are no explanations for doing this when the disks are separated.  Can this be done? If so, how do I do this?  Disk 0 is shown above Disk 1 in the Disk Management window:


No, it can't be done (at least not the way you think).

Then there's there a way to do it?

There are many ways to do it but 1) you don't have the hardware (RAID) and 2) you wouldn't be here asking if you were capable of doing it safely even with the necessary hardware, 3) it's a bad idea anyway and 4) you don't even have backups.
